# Update an particular element in an array if it already exist with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

During a `.click` action on element, I create an array like this:

```
var arr = [];

$('[data-action="change_status"]').click(function(event) {
    $(this).data('status', 'newValue');

    arr.push({
        current_status: $(this).data('status'),
        current_date: $(this).data('date'),
        current_roomid: $(this).data('roomid')
    });
});
```

So for each click on elements, I put the id of the element and some other informations in the array.

My problem is if the user click two times on the same element, it creates two rows in this array. How can I check that an id already exists into the array and how can I update it with the last clicked value ?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="dateClose" data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="45" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div class="dateClose" data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="46" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
<div class="dateClose" data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="46" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div class="dateClose" data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="47" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant html code so that I can create a working snippet for you.

Comment: Hello @AniketG, I've put some HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object indexed by something unique to each element instead of an array, for example, using the `roomid`:

```
const obj = {};

$('[data-action="change_status"]').click(function(event) {
    $(this).data('status', 'newValue');
    const current_roomid = $(this).data('roomid');
    obj[current_roomid] = {
        current_status: $(this).data('status'),
        current_date: $(this).data('date'),
        current_roomid
    };
});
```

If nothing is reliably constant enough, you can use a `Map` instead, which allows for non-primitive keys (such as elements):

```
const map = new Map();

$('[data-action="change_status"]').click(function(event) {
  $(this).data('status', 'newValue');
  const current_roomid = $(this).data('roomid');
  map.set(this, {
    current_status: $(this).data('status'),
    current_date: $(this).data('date'),
    current_roomid
  });
});
```

Live snippet:

```js
const map = new Map();

$('[data-action="change_status"]').click(function(event) {
  $(this).data('status', 'newValue');
  const current_roomid = $(this).data('roomid');
  map.set(this, {
    current_status: $(this).data('status'),
    current_date: $(this).data('date'),
    current_roomid
  });
  console.log(map.size);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dateClose" data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="45" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div class="dateClose" data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="46" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
<div class="dateClose" data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="46" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div class="dateClose" data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="47" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The problem is I can have more than one element with `roomId` and `date`.

Comment: Then use a `Map` instead, with the elements as the keys

Comment: I continue to have multiple items in the array even if I clicked few times on the same element...

Comment: I can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/g4Lf6hqy/ When a previously clicked element gets clicked again, the Map's size doesn't increase

Comment: Hum curious. I think something is block in my code. Let me check. Thanks.

Comment: See snippet in answer with your HTML, appears to work just fine

Comment: It doesn't work due to this line: `const map = new Map();`. Do you know what can cause this problem?

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work"? The code works just fine in the snippet, and in the fiddle.

Comment: Perhaps my jQuery version ?

Comment: No, `Map` is not a jQuery object, it's a DOM object. What exactly is the error you're encountering?

Comment: Strange, I put `var arr = new Map();` and now it's working well.

Comment: Could you please let me know how can use incremental key. Actually, the key looks somme HTML code. Thanks.